# Adding a "Child" or SubItem to ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-arrayadapter

I can't find instructions to add a child item to my expandable list anywhere. All I can find is 50 questions on how to change the background color.

Right now, I am using this code to create a normal list view:

```
 public String listArray[] = { "Example1", "Example2", "Example3", "Example4", "Example5"}; 
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main2);  
      listV = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.exListView);
      listV.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listArray));      
  }
```

But how would I go about adding sub or child items underneath example1, example2, etc..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, you need to use an ExpandableListView instead of a ListView. Then throw in a [SimpleExpandableListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleExpandableListAdapter.html) and maintain a reference to your group (parent) and child data objects.

Then it's as easy as:

```
mChildData.get(groupIndex).get(childIndex).put(...);
mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Could you give me an example of SimpleExpandableListAdapter? Im pretty new to android, and dont quite understand all the arguments. The android site says this is what i need correct?                public SimpleExpandableListAdapter (Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> groupData, int groupLayout, String[] groupFrom, int[] groupTo, List<? extends List<? extends Map<String, ?>>> childData, int childLayout, String[] childFrom, int[] childTo)        Edit: sorry cant get the code tags to work :/

Comment: You might have fixed this already but other people might need it, i found this tutorial very helpful : http://www.journaldev.com/9942/android-expandablelistview-example-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Basic example for expandablelistview is.. [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/)....

Implement OnChildClickListener in your Activity and implemet this method..

```
@Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

   //Add new chid data in your list (ex ArrayLis or Array whatever you use)
  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() // BaseExpandableListAdapter's adapter...


return true;
}
```

Is it work work for you?